# Instagram API Endpoint in array

Tags: instagram

I have a basic php script that gets my last 30 instagram pictures. It just uses the media/recent endpoint url.. That works fine.

Looks like this

```php
    $userid = "ID";
$accessToken = "ACCESSTOKEN";

// Gets data
function fetchData($url){
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $result;
}

// Pulls and parses data.
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=30");
$result = json_decode($result);
```

And echo the output like this:

```php
<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>
```

But how can I put the endpoint url's in a array and be able to echo comments and likes in the same way..

I've tried using instaphp, but it's really slow and creates an access token for each visit..

Comment: You can decode json into array. $result = json_decode($result, true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the full result set, you should be able to get things this way:

Likes:

```
<?= $post->likes->count ?>
<?= $post->likes->data->username ?>
<?= $post->likes->data->full_name ?>
<?= $post->likes->data->id ?>
<?= $post->likes->data->profile_picture ?>
```

Comments:

```
<?= $post->comments->count ?>
etc
```

Check out the documentation for the response: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

Comment: This is great! Big thanks Bill! I thought i had to use different endpoint url to get this data.